# Laravel dd() stopped working after I uninstalled ignition error page package

Tags: laravel

Since uninstalling ignition, if I use dd() anywhere in my code the entire output of my laravel app stops and the page returned is blank with no html at all.

Can someone please assist me to resolve this, it's driving me mad and making it very hard to debug a project I'm working on.

It's definitely related to ignition as if I reinstall ignition via composer dd() starts working again.

Just to make things crystal clear - I don't want to use ignition so responses such as "just install it again" are not a solution.

Comment: So don't uninstall Ignition.

Comment: @miken32 comment of the day ! Nailed it haha

Comment: I thought this was obvious but I don't like ignition that much and don't want the extra packages installed so just want to revert back to what I had before installing it.

Comment: Sift through your error logs. All of them, Laravel ones, PHP ones, webserver ones. Ignition doesn't seem to do anything to `dd` it just adds its own `ddd` helper so I don't know why it would affect `dd` to be honest. Couldn't hurt to delete `vendor` and run `composer install` again (without ignition in your composer.json)

Comment: If you don't like Ignition then I think Whoops is still used if it's present. But really this question doesn't make any sense. It's an extra couple of hundred kb on your development box. It's not worth losing sleep over.

Comment: I also find that ignition produces different and inaccurate errors from what whoops shows.  That is actually my main reason for wanting to uninstall it.

Comment: @apokryfos the old delete vendor trick did it, thank you.    If you want to add an answer for this feel free ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea from @apokryfos to delete the vendor folder and then run `composer install` again did the job.